# MySQL 5.6, не подбирается ключ в выборке с IN при передаче значений разных типов

Tags: mysql, sql, key

Наткнулся при анализе потери производительности SQL-запросов на одну странность, которую просто пофиксить, но её причины совсем не ясны.

Имеется таблица, `user_test_answers` в InnoDB. Её структура не имеет значение, чтобы не путать, даю только колонки/ключи в тестовой выборке:

```
`test_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`evaluator_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 KEY `EVALUATOR` (`test_id`,`evaluator_user_id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `OTU` (`test_id`,`idtask`,`iduser`),
```

А дальше последовательность EXPLAIN-тестов запроса с одним смыслом, обратите внимание на выбранный key:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT count(1) FROM `test_table` WHERE test_id IN('18616', '-1') AND (status != -1) AND (evaluator_user_id = '1');
+----+-------------+-------------------------------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+------+------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table             | type  | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                              |
+----+-------------+-------------------------------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+------+------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | user_test_answers | range | OTU,EVALUATOR | EVALUATOR | 9       | NULL |    1 | Using index condition; Using where |
+----+-------------+-------------------------------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+------+------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT count(1) FROM `test_table` WHERE test_id IN('18616', -1) AND (status != -1) AND (evaluator_user_id = '1');
+----+-------------+-------------------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table             | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------------------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | user_test_answers | ALL  | OTU,EVALUATOR | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 9365600 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------------------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT count(1) FROM `test_table` WHERE test_id IN(18616, -1) AND (status != -1) AND (evaluator_user_id = '1');
+----+-------------+-------------------------------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+------+------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table             | type  | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                              |
+----+-------------+-------------------------------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+------+------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | user_test_answers | range | OTU,EVALUATOR | EVALUATOR | 9       | NULL |    1 | Using index condition; Using where |
+----+-------------+-------------------------------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+------+------------------------------------+
```

Подскажите пожалуйста: почему во втором запросе ключ не выбирается, хотя возможных ключей 2? Может быть это баг, и поправлено в более поздних версиях, а может быть есть сакральный смысл?

Совсем нелогично, что ключа нет в одном запросе, а в соседних есть - логично, что mysql должен был сделать CAST входящих параметров в нужный ему тип, а не делать зависимость выбранного ключа от типов переменных множества..

Comment: А где `WHERE test_id IN(18616, '-1')`? *логично, что mysql должен был сделать CAST входящих параметров в нужный ему тип* Раз логично - а не скажешь ли, в какой именно, и какая в том логика? Для значений, преобразуемых несколько раз - для каждого отдельного преобразования момент и тип...

Comment: @Akina это предположение: логика в том, что тип значения во множестве, ну никак не должен влиять на выбор ключа, т.к. это с точки зрения языка крайне неочевидно, а в нашем деле, что неочевидно - то не верно, особенно в СУБД, которую юзает каждый второй компьютер в мире. Соответственно в коде, который использует SQL - запросы создаются построителями, которые сохраняют типы "как есть", а программисты не заморачиваются с типами, т.к. ну никак не ждут там беды: вот и получится, что если эта "особенность" sql массовая - то очень множество IT-продуктов могут незаметно для себя страдать)

Comment: *тип значения во множестве, ну никак не должен влиять на выбор ключа* Одно дело - искать значения индексированного поля. Это легко и просто. Совсем другое - дополнительно заниматься при этом преобразованием типов. Преобразование - это неявное использование функции. А индекс по полю не может использоваться для оптимизации выборки, когда это поле является аргументом функции.